# Need to update object instead of adding

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code which is supposed to update my address record in firebase. However, instead of updating, its adding new fields.

Here's the code:

```
   Future<void> updateAddress (Address address)  async{
      final url = 'https://m&m.firebaseio.com/address/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
   await  http.patch(url, body:json.encode({
       'phoneNumber':address.phoneNumber,
        'name':address.name, 
        'details':address.details, 
        'alternatePhone':address.alternatePhone 
      })); 
      _items.first = address;
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

Here's how it looks after I execute the update function:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I see that you are updating all the values of user so instead of patch you can also use `http.put`
like this

```
 Future<void> updateAddress (Address address)  async{
  final url = 'https://m&m.firebaseio.com/address/$userId.json?auth=$authToken';
   await  http.put(url, body:json.encode({
   'phoneNumber':address.phoneNumber,
    'name':address.name, 
    'details':address.details, 
    'alternatePhone':address.alternatePhone 
  })); 
  _items.first = address;
  notifyListeners();
  }
```

also refer these docs for more info [firebase realtime database docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update)

feel free to comment and ask more

Comment: @Akshiit, thanks brother. Can you help me on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64952094/not-able-to-render-data-on-form

Comment: I have answered that question too have a look there 

Comment: here's another if you could help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65131521/extracting-data-from-database-in-dart

Answer (score 1):

```
// Create an initial document reference to update:
var docRef = db.collection("address").doc("$authToken");
docRef.set({
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { alternatePhone: "125478848844", details: "212 jenn", name: "James", phoneNumber: "2142889776" },
    age: 12
});
// To update fields in nested objects:
db.collection("address").doc("$authToken").update({
    "alternatePhone": 125478848844,
    "details": "212 jenn",
    "name": "James"
});
```

Comment: please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you 

Comment: this is not quiet what I was looking for. But I'll give you a plus for pitching in.